# Android - evaluatejavascript for before api-level 19

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-api-levels

`evaluatejavascript` is available API-level 19 and later. It has a callback. I know that I can use `loadUrl` instead of `evaluatejavascript` for before API-level 19. But how can I handle return value from script? Is there a solution for this?

```
String script = "function(){ return "abc"}()";
mywebview.loadUrl(script);
```

Comment: Your code has wrong combination of quotes. You can use `JavascriptInterface` to return value from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) for this. Then the JavaScript can use the interface to communicate back to your code.

Example code:

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void returnValue(String value){
        Log.d("JsObject", "Got value [" + value + "]");
    }
}
mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
mywebview.loadUrl("javascript:function(){ injectedObject.returnValue('abc')}()");
```